# PuPHPet: cannot include Apache custom directory fragment, Vagrant Up crashes

Tags: apache, symfony, vagrant, puphpet

I use puphpet.com to generate config for dev environment based on vagrant and puppet

So, i try to include file directory.conf as Apache directory custom fragment (for Symfony framework) in my config.yaml

```
custom_fragment: 'directory.conf'
```

File contents:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

I put this file in the root of synced folder 
When i run Vagrant up process finishes with several errors:

```
=> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_apache/Exec[Create apache webroot]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_apache/File[/var/run/apache2/ssl_mutex]/ensure: created
==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_apache/File[/var/run/apache2/ssl_mutex]: Scheduling refresh of Service[httpd]
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Failed to call refresh: Could not start Service[httpd]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/apache2 start' returned 1: 
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Could not start Service[httpd]: Execution of '/etc/init.d/apache2 start' returned 1: 
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_apache/Exec[Set /var/www/html/index.html contents]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Info: Creating state file /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml
==> default: Notice: Finished catalog run in 447.56 seconds
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If i clear this parameter in config.yaml - everything goes ok.I tried to specify both relative and absolute path (like 'w:/vagrant/symphpet/directory.conf') and got the same errors.

My config.yaml:

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        hostname: local.symphet
        memory: '3072'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.101
            forwarded_port:
                vflnp_hgs9gkr2mkgs:
                    host: '9698'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: 'on'
                showgui: '0'
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_enhw9i33oc2f:
                source: 'w:/vagrant/symphpet'
                target: /var/www/symphpet
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: en_US.UTF-8
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_xyjshf9hxmb6:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_port: '443'
            ssl_protocols: ''
            ssl_ciphers: ''
            rewrite_to_https: '1'
            spdy: '1'
            locations:
                nxvl_wzyv1axir27d:
                    location: /
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'off'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                nxvl_jk2yw7iakib2:
                    location: '~ \.php$'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'off'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_9120k99j7eej:
            servername: symphpet.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.symphpet.dev
            docroot: /var/www/symphpet/web
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
                - 'umask 0002'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_irm91amrcpsc:
                    path: /var/www/symphpet/web
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: 'directory.conf'
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_n3m5ulu8d1bv:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '56'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_culgw6h1gdeo:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.19.0
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '1'
    npm_packages: {  }
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini:
        hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
        hhvm.server.port: '9000'
        hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
        hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
    php_ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        date.timezone: UTC
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.6'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mysqlnu_hwls7ddqlxgr:
            name: dbuser
            password: dbuser123
    databases:
        mysqlnd_5zin6thnaify:
            name: db
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_h1sgjmtbfgp1:
            user: dbuser
            table: 'db.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '10.0'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mariadbnu_uzqkvk7d2ci8:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mariadbnd_g8up6ozvn1o0:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mariadbng_27k387wsgixj:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.3'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
    adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '1'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mailcatcher:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 1.4.1
        java_install: true
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Comment: can you run vagrant in debug mode and/or highlight the error from the apache log, it should give you good hint of the error root cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set it to an absolute path to the file, not relative.

Comment: Juan, thank you. Absolute path in VM or in the host?

Comment: @StepanYudin it has to be visible within the VM.